# Standard serialization or custom?

Tags: php, serialization

can anyone recognize this format (if it is a standard format), or should I explode it manually to get arrays? Thanks.

```
{ coords : {lon : 7.41891, lat : 43.73253}, address : "", zipCode : "98000", city : "Monaco", sK : "Monaco", sQ : "852", fV : "", fZ : "98000 Monaco", fW : "- MC - Monaco: Monaco (98000)", gf : "31NDFzeHoxMGNORE11TnpNeU5UTT1jTnk0ME1UZzVNUT09", reflexId : "84167", areaLabel : "Monaco", jalon : 4}
```

YAML to VarExport gives this but then fails.

```
array (
  'coords' => 
  array (
    'lon' => 20.48406,
    'lat' => 44.80572,
  ),
)
```

Solution:

```
$data = preg_replace('#([\w]+) :#is', '"$1" :', $data);
```

Result:

```
array (
  'coords' => 
  {
     'lon' => 7.41891,
     'lat' => 43.73253,
  },
  'address' => '',
  'zipCode' => '98000',
  'city' => 'Monaco',
  'sK' => 'Monaco',
  'sQ' => '852',
  'fV' => '',
  'fZ' => '98000 Monaco',
  'fW' => '- MC - Monaco: Monaco (98000)',
  'gf' => '31NDFzeHoxMGNORE11TnpNeU5UTT1jTnk0ME1UZzVNUT09',
  'reflexId' => '84167',
  'areaLabel' => 'Monaco',
  'jalon' => 4,
)
```

Comment: Note: The `[]` in `[\w]` are redundant. `\w` would be enough.

Comment: I used a-zA-Z0-9 first, forgot to delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's valid JavaScript code and *almost* JSON. For it to be valid JSON it would need to have the object property names enclosed in double quotes and have the array items separated by commas.

This:

```
$text = preg_replace('/(\r?\n){2}/', ',', trim($text));
$text = preg_replace('/([{,])\s?([a-z0-9_]+)\s?:/i', '$1"$2":',$text);
print_r(json_decode($text));
```

will work for your example.

**But you should not use it as it will fail when there are `,` or `{` inside values!**

The safest approach would be to construct a parser yourself.

Comment: Yes, it is valid, but I am unable to decode it as JSON, decoding like YAML gives some result, but fails at some point. Thanks.

Comment: Closest match :) I will use it only for this, not anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like json serialization to me, so fairly standard. :)

Comment: I'll give it a go later once i am at a computer unless someone else figures it out in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

Bad JSON. I would convert the hash keys to strings and then `json_decode`. You can do that with the [PHP Tokenizer](http://php.net/Tokenizer) fairly simply.

```
function parse($code) {
    $result = '';
    $tokens = tokens_get_all('<?php ' . $code);
    array_shift($tokens); // drop <?php
    foreach ($tokens as $token) {
        if (!is_array($token)) {
            $result .= $token;
            continue;
        }

        if ($token[0] == T_STRING) {
            $token[1] = '\'' . addslashes($token[1]) . '\'';
        }

        $result .= $token[1];
    }

    return json_decode($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, it definitely looks like improperly formatted JSON. However, it's not too far off. In fact, with two regular expressions you could easily convert the string to proper JSON.

```
Find:
    /(\w+)\s+\:/
Replace:
    "$1" :

Find:
    /(})(\s+{)/
Replace:
    $1,$2
```

You can do it like this in PHP:

```
$good_json = preg_replace(array('/(\w+)\s+\:/i','/(})(\s+{)/'), array('"\1" :', '\1,\2'), $bad_json);
var_dump( json_decode($good_json) );
```